# Replacing a feature class in a work version, or emptying it\Splitting features by mask?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I am working in a versioned database, in a specific feature class. After changes are made to this feature class (a copy outside of the versioned geodatabase) I want to be able to "update" the named feature class in the versioned database. I want this to happen with the click of a button (using Modelbuilder or Arcpy).

Further clarification:  I have a work version from the default and I "export" data from this by using clip. This clipped data is given to an **external** user to edit, change geometry and attribute table etc. I then get supplied with the new data and need to implement it into the work version, replacing old data with new data, before reconciling. The main issue is that almost everything done in ArcMap creates a new output.

So far I have found different options, but none of them do the job. These are the options I have tried so far:

- Delete features and then append (This "works" but it takes over 3 hours, this is way too long)
- Use Delete (This clears the entire database, I only need to replace 1 feature class with the same name)
- The update tool (When polygons are "made smaller" this fills up the empty space with a polygon of it's own)

The delete features would work if I could split by mask (other feature class) and then delete the selection, but I do not know of any way to do this.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1

Comment: None of the options you have offered are in the access modalities of versioned workflows.  It's unclear as to what you are attempting, or how the edits manifest in the state tree, but it's generally easier to work *with* the versioned model than to try to circumvent it. You should probably review Checkout-Checkin replication (aka Disconnected Editing), but you'd still need to reconcile versioned edits with the check-in state.

Comment: I'll try to explain it in a different way - I have a work version from the default and I "export" data from this by using clip. This clipped data is given to a different user to edit, change geometry and attribute table etc. I then get supplied with the new data and need to implement it into the work version, replacing old data with new data, before reconciling. The main issue is that almost everything done in ArcMap creates a new output. I will take a look at disconnected editing! If anything else pops to mind, please let me know, everything helps.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question with this clarification. You seem to be attempting Disconnected Editing without using the versioning support for same.

Comment: I have looked into Disconnected editing and the check-in/check-out tools, is there a way to replicate (check-out) a single feature class? Rather than the entire feature dataset?

Comment: No. This is why feature datasets should only be used when the feature classes will be  edited together.